# How to scroll to the last message sent when viewdidload? in swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, chat, swift4

Currently, I have tried

```
func scrollToBottom(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self,messageArrat.count-1, section: 0)
        self.messageTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath,at:.bottom,animated:true)
    } 
}
```

However it does not seem to work, outputting

```
Thread 16: ESC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc)
UITableView.scrollToRow(at:at:animated:) must be used from main thread only
```

I call the function right after setting delegate and datasource in viewdidload.

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots. The error message ***must be used from the main thread only*** is pretty clear. Why do you dispatch it to a background thread?

Comment: Should I add more context? because none of the fixes bellow worked fully ->

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue, you said you are calling this from the viewDidLoad, try moving it to the viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews instead. Also remove from background thread as you are manipulating the UI and that needs to happen on the main thread.

Comment: It worked thanks! why is it that it worked when I placed in in viewdidapear as opposed to didload?

Comment: The table hasn’t been drawn to the screen yet so it can’t be scrolled.

Comment: Since it solved your issue, I moved my comment to an answer so you can tag it as correct. This will help others searching SO find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a timing issue, you said you are calling this from the viewDidLoad, try moving it to the viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews instead. Also remove from background thread as you are manipulating the UI and that needs to happen on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: please provide your code as text not as Image.

Now to your problem, you are trying to scroll to the last row in a global queue, but all UI-Updates must happen in the Main Thread, so simply remove the DispatchQueue, or if you are not in the main thread, you can write `DispatchQueue.main` instead of global

E.g.:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //code Here
}
```

But i think you doesnt need the DispatchQueue at all so try to omit it completely.

Comment: I have tried both but still get this warning, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xf

Answer (score 0):

It likes to work on this main thread and not in the background because it is related to the UI

try this code:

```
 func scrollToBottom() {

       DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messageArrat.count-1, section: 0)                        
                    self.messageTableView.scrollToRow(at:  indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
             } 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing code in ".async" closure you starting a new thread, and the error message literally tells you do not do that.

Delete `DispatchQueue` stuff and that's it.

And please post text, description and all that stuff to help community.

Comment: I have tried both but still get this warning, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xf

Comment: check whether your `func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)` returns `messageArray.count -1 ` as well

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to add DispatchQueue:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messageArrat.count-1, section: 0)
self.messageTableView.scrollToRow(at:  indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

> And if you want DispatchQueue then add main queue like that:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messageArrat.count-1, section: 0)
    self.messageTableView.scrollToRow(at:  indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I have tried both but still get this warning, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xf

Answer (score 0):

May be index path must be out of bound, try checking number of rows before scrolling . Also do this all oprations on main thread.

Comment: The result I get is 0, -1